# jquery Looping (.each)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I have an object that looks like the following:

```
Node{
     name: "root",
     level: 0,
     children: Array[14],
     parent: null,
     id: 0
}
```

And inside `Node.children`...

```
Node.children[
    {
     name: "child1",
     level: 1,
     children: Array[1],
     parent: root,
     id: 1
    },
    {
     name: "child2",
     level: 1,
     children: Array[1],
     parent: root,
     id: 2
    },
    {
     name: "child3",
     level: 1,
     children: Array[2],
     parent: root,
     id: 3
    },
]
```

And inside Node.children[1].children ...

```
Node.children[1].children[
        {
         name: "child1-1",
         level: 2,
         children: Array[0],
         parent: child1,
         id: 4
        }
]
```

What I need is to loop through the Node object and try and match every "`id`" with a value given.  For example...

```
$.each(Node, function(i, nodes){
    $.each(nodes, function (i2, nodes2){
        if (nodes2.id == 5){
            //do something
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: That looks legit, I think this is the best way to do it. `$.each()` is your tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a function you can call recursively:

```
function checkNode(node, action, id) {
  if (node.id === id)
    action(node);

  var kids = node.children || [];

  $.each( kids, 
    function(i,n) {
      checkNode(n, action, id);
    }
  );
}
```

called as:

```
checkNode( 
  node, 
  function(n) { alert(n.name); }, 
  5
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.each(Node.children, function(i, inode){
    $.each(inode.children, function (i2, inode2){
        if (inode2.id === 5){
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```